# Can I apply for an Iranian visa in the Republic of Georgia?

Tags: visas, georgia-country, iran, embassies, australian-citizens

I've done a bit of searching on the net and haven't come up with much.

I intend to stay in the Republic of Georgia for a while and at some point take a trip to Iran.

As an Australian citizen I believe I'll need a visa. I can find that there is an Iranian embassy in Armenia but Georgia only has an Iranian consulate.

Can I apply for a visa in the consulate in Georgia or will I have to wait until I get to Armenia and apply there in the embassy?

I'd prefer to apply in Georgia since it will be much cheaper for me to spend time there than in Armenia and the tourist visa terms are much more generous.

Comment: Were you asked why you didn't apply for an Iranian visa back home ?

Comment: @Blackbird57: I didn't end up going to Iran on that trip. Usually I don't like to plan my trips in advance. Sometimes that makes some visas trickier. Often it makes other visas cheaper.

Comment: Visa applications are typically handled by consulates, not embassies; if an embassy does that sort of thing, it is usually through a "consular section."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Iran Embassy/consulates in Africa, North & south America, Europe, Asia, Oceania](http://www.irantravelingcenter.com/embassy.htm) there is an Iranian embassy in Tbilisi so you should be able to apply for a visa.

Comment: And they're definitely not like China and Russia who will only allow me to apply in a country where I have residency?

Comment: Iran has no such constraints. Many non Turkish people apply in Istanbul for crossing at Doğubeyazıt.

Comment: There is also an Iranian consulate in Batumi (near the Turkish border). There is also an Iranian consulate 160km over the border at Trabzon, Turkey which is famous among travellers for being the easiest place in the world to get an Iran visa.

Comment: Anyway visa applications are typically handled by consulates.  Embassies that handle these sorts of things generally do so through a "consular section."

Answer (score 5):

Yes - you can – the embassy is opened from 9:30. Visa costs approx. 50 EUR.

**Address:**

- Iranian Embassy in Tbilisi, Georgia
- Chavchavadze Street 80 Tbilisi Georgia

**Phone:**

- (+995) 32 291 36 56
- (+995) 32 291 36 58

**Fax:**

- (+995) 32 291 36 28

**E-mail:**

- embassy@iran.ge
- info@iran.ge

**Website:**

> http://www.embassypages.com/missions/embassy21563/

As noted in empassy website:

> **Facts about the Embassy**
>
> **Iran in Georgia**: In addition to the embassy in Tbilisi, Iran also has a consulate general in Batumi.
>
> **Georgia in Iran**: Georgia maintains an embassy in Tehran.
>
> The Iranian embassy is one of 59 foreign representations in Georgia,
>   and one of 51 foreign representations in Tbilisi. See more @ the [Georgia EmbassyPages](http://www.embassypages.com/georgia).
>
> The Iranian embassy in Tbilisi is one of 140 Iranian diplomatic and
>   consular representations abroad. See more @ the [Iran EmbassyPages](http://www.embassypages.com/iran).
>
> Please contact the embassy in Tbilisi directly for inquiries and questions regarding visa regulations and passport requirements.

Additional sources (from Polish blogs, but you may use Google Translate):

- http://www.osmol.pl/2013/04/nie-mam-pana-kodu-do-wizy-i-co-mi-pan-zrobisz/
- http://fizyk-w-podrozy.blogspot.com/2011/10/jak-zdobyc-wize-do-iranu-w-trabzonie.html
- http://www.osmol.pl/2013/06/wiza-do-iranu-jak-dostac-i-gdzie-aplikowac/