# What is the usual time taken to process an Iranian visa for a German?

Tags: visas, iran, german-citizens

I'm planning to visit Iran in a couple of months. I'm German and when skimming through some stuff on the embassy website I couldn't find any helpful information.

What is the usual visa processing time?

Comment: Although it's kinda late just for the record here you find a perfect answer to this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/how-to-get-a-visa-for-iran