# Traveling to Iran & Israel with British and Spanish passports

Tags: uk-citizens, dual-nationality, israel, iran

I'm planning to travel to Middle East at the end of the year. My aim is to visit Israel, Palestine, Jordan Turkey and Iran. Then I'll fly to Egypt and from there I'll continue my trip.

As I'll be bringing Spanish and British passports I was planning to use both to avoid the issues of having an Israel stamp on the passport. I'm aware Israel issues a visa card separated to the passport, but I've also read that when crossing border to Jordan I could get a stamp ON the passport pages from the Israeli border, and definitely stamps from Jordanian border.

In order to easy this I've thought two options which both of them pose questions:

Option 1 (Preferred as it's the cheapest)

Israel (British passport)

Palestine – Jordan – back to Israel (British passport)

Turkey – (Spanish passport)

Iran – (Spanish passport)*

1. When entering Iran using Spanish passport, I'll still have with me a UK passport – possibly with a Israeli stamp. Is it wise to just hide it somewhere? What are the chances of them to find out? What would be de consecuences?

Option 2

Iran (Spanish Passport)**

Turkey (British Passport)

Israel (British passport)***

Palestine – Jordan – back to Israel (British passport)

2. When entering Iran I'd still have with me a UK passport – no Israeli stamps on this option. Would that be fine? My doubt here is that as British citizen I'd need to visit Iran with a tour or with sponsor. Although I'll not be using UK passport, they could find out and apply this rule to me?
3. I'll come into Israel with a recently issued UK passport and I expect to be questioned. Should I assume that I'd be requested to show the Spanish passport and give explanation of my Trip to Iran?

Comment: Possible dupe of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel

Comment: Hi @JonathanReez thanks for sharing this tread. I'm aware of how to use two passports. My enquiry is more on how safe are the options I described to visit both Iran and Israel and what are the chances -if any- that I can get questioned or having any trouble. I would really appreciate if anyone would have anything to share in their experience.
Thank you!

Comment: Also note that Israel no longer issues passport stamps http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/61953/9009

Comment: Thanks @JonathanReez , I was also aware of this with the possible inconvenience:
" At land crossings they will still issue you a stamp unless you explicitly tell them not to (and also depends on their mood). However if you are entering via a land crossing, such as Jordan, you will get an exit stamp at the Jordan boarder anyway which shows you are entering Israel."
I think that in any case the biggest issue here is to know if carrying an UK passport (with or without Israel stamp) could mean a problem to enter Iran.
Thanks!!

Comment: Not a full answer, but as a UK citizen you would need a guide, however thanks to your Spanish citizenship that is most likely waived, see [Visiting Iran as a dual EU-American citizen](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/82140/32134)

Answer (score 4):

There is a few aspects to your question that I will address separately below. Note however that we do not plan itineraries so that choice will be up to you.

- > 2. When entering Iran I'd still have with me a UK passport – no Israeli stamps on this option. Would that be fine? My doubt here is that as British citizen I'd need to visit Iran with a tour or with sponsor. Although I'll not be using UK passport, they could find out and apply this rule to me?

This should be fine actually. We had [a similar question for a Dutch/U.S. dual national here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/82140/32134) who contacted both his Dutch embassy in Iran and the Iranian embassy in Hague and both confirmed it was fine to enter with the Spanish passport even though he also has U.S. citizenship. If you are very anxious you could still confirm with your respective embassies but I would expect no trouble.

- > 1. When entering Iran using Spanish passport, I'll still have with me a UK passport – possibly with a Israeli stamp. Is it wise to just hide it somewhere? What are the chances of them to find out? What would be de consecuences?

Honestly I would not risk this one, but that is my opinion as a fairly risk-averse person. The point is, if you are breaking their rules, why carry evidence of that with you?
Instead could you leave your British passport with Israeli/Jordan stamps with a trusted person or even mail it home?

- > 3. I'll come into Israel with a recently issued UK passport and I expect to be questioned. Should I assume that I'd be requested to show the Spanish passport and give explanation of my Trip to Iran?

YMMV. Emigration/immigration in Israel can be incredibly harsh and a trip to Iran sure does not help, in itself it is not a no-go either. Have a true and plausible story for everything and be able to prove it in case.